# How to merge content of enduser defined to DataTemplate in WPF, some like change DataTemplate content at runtime

Tags: wpf, merge, datatemplate

I want to change DataTemplate's content at runtime, the content is designed by enduser, and saved in a file as xaml format.

the DataTemplate is defined like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate1">
    <Grid>
        <Canvas x:Name="canvas1" />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

and the content designed by enduser like this:

```
<Canvas x:Name="canvas1">
    <Label ...>
    ...
</Canvas>
```

I want to meger the content designed by enduser to the datatemplate using code:

```
DataTemplate templateObj = FindResource("DataTemplate1");
```

and now I don't know how to change the templateObj to merge the content, at last the templateObj will like this:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate1">
        <Grid>
            <Canvas x:Name="canvas1">
                <Label ...>
                ...
            </Canvas>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I don't think you can marge two DataTemplates. Try create one parent template and one child  which base on parent template. Change template use:

```
DataTemplate summary = this.FindResource("SimpleTemplate") as DataTemplate;
YourControl.ItemTemplate = summary;
```

Comment: OK,Thank you.I use a child DataTemplate to solve it.<DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate1">
        <Grid>
            <ContentControl ContentTemplateSelector="..."/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
in the ContentTemplateSelector, use XamlReader to Generate a DataTemplate with specified content.

Answer (score 0):

OK,Thank you, Aleksey.

I use a child DataTemplate to solve it. just like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate1">
        <Grid>
            <ContentControl ContentTemplateSelector="..."/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

in the ContentTemplateSelector, use XamlReader to Generate a DataTemplate with specified content.